# toggle button doesn't work in chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, filter, toggle, haml

i have one line of code to make a toggle button to filter my data. so, if user click this toggle button, dropdown lists would appear to filter my table.
the code look like this:

`link_to_with_icon(t("shared.filters.toggle_filters"), "#", "icon-filter", class: "btn toggle-button filter-toggle", "data-to-toggle" => "filters")`

couple weeks ago, this toggle button worked well, but not not anymore. i tried to clean and precompile the assets. but it doesnt give any result. any idea?
thanks in advance!

Comment: is it because of this warning : 
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.  ??

Comment: i tried in all browsers, in case there's problem with my chrome. but, neither firefox, safari or IE. :(

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with a dropdown menu and sorted by doing:

```
<%= button_to.........%>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! but i tried by cleaning the assets without precompiling. and it works.